# android studio how to add github library as jar file to run it offline?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i want to use this github library `https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad` in my android application but i don't want to use it as url online `implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'` because my pc cannot have internet connection AT ALL.

i want to use this library as a jar file if possible, note that in my .gradle caches (C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.gcacace) folder i have the folder of this library cached copied from another PC but still android studio cannot run the application and cannot see the cache of the library